# Convergence of the integral $\lambda \int_{0}^{1/\lambda} Re(\phi(u)) \, du$

Tags: integration, analysis

I was trying to find out why 
$$\lambda \int_{0}^{1/\lambda} Re(\phi(u)) \,du$$
converges to 0 as $\lambda$ goes to infinity. Here $\phi$ is a continuous function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ with $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: You can simplify the problem. Any continuous real function $f$ can be the real part of a continuous complex function. So you can study the integral $$\lambda\int_0^{1/\lambda} f(u)du$$ when $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h=1/\lambda$. We're trying to compute (see my comment):
$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^hf(u)du}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^hf(u)du-\int_0^0f(u)du}h$$

which is the right derivative at $t=0$ of the function
$$t\mapsto\int_0^tf(u)du$$
Now apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and the contituity of $f$ to conclude that this limit is $f(0)=0$.

Comment: thanks that's a little embarrassing that I didn't think of the fundamental theorem ...